# content = content.replace

Tags: javascript, regex, document

How can I eliminate the hyphens in my example? Simply copy and paste:

```
<tt>A-B-C-D-E-F-G</tt>
```

into the text box labeled process in http://jsfiddle.net/WVUYX/17/ and click process.

the output I am looking for is just: ABCDEFG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another replace that removes hypens:

```
content = content.replace(/(<tt>)(.*?)(<\/tt>)/g, '$2')
content = content.replace(/-/g,'');
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/WVUYX/20/

or you could remove them both in a single step by shortening your first replace:

```
content = content.replace(/<\/?tt>|-/g, '')
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/WVUYX/21/

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

`content = content.replace(/(<tt>)(.*?)(<\/tt>)/g, '$2');`

With
`content = content.replace(/(<tt>)(.*?)(<\/tt>)/g, '$2').replace(/-/g, '');`

And you will get your desired result.